# During "make" process for AOSP build, Can I check a progress ratio?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I'm building aosp.
But I can't know a that's progressratio.
Does "make" have a option for checking progress ratio?

Comment: No, there is no facility in make to show progress.  That's because make has no idea now many jobs it will need to run: it doesn't make a plan and then execute the plan; instead it just keeps building out-of-date stuff until everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no standard way to monitor the build progress, I find that checking the size of *out/* to be the easiest; however, that will require you know the size of a full built out directory after you build already once.

The easy way:

```
du -hs out
```

The fun way:

```
sudo apt-get install figlet

while true; do clear;figlet $(du -hs out | cut -f1);sleep 1; done
```